# Is it valid to grab a tag by its two identical class values?

Tags: html, css, class

If the HTML code has two identical class values, like this:

```
<div class="aaa aaa">
</div>
```

Is it valid to grab it by the two same values within CSS, like this?

```
div.aaa.aaa { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having `<div class="aaa aaa">`, is the same as having `<div class="aaa">`.
`div.aaa.aaa` is valid, as well as `div.aaa`, and they both select the same elements.

`div.aaa.aaa` looks for `<div>`s with `class=aaa` and `class=aaa`, which is redundant.

Comment: One overrides the other, got it!